# Wordpress Related Plugin - only show when related content

Tags: plugins, php

I'm using the Wordpress related plugin : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/related/

Which uses the following markup to call the plugin:

```
<?php echo $related->show(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

I would like to add a title and a division around the plugin... but would only like this to display if there is a related post/page. How should I modify the code?

This is the result I would like to see, but only when there is related content:

```
<div class="related"><strong>Related products</strong><br />
<?php echo $related->show(get_the_ID()); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure if this would work but this is where I'd start:

```
<?php $related_content = $related->show(get_the_ID()); ?>
<?php if($related_content): ?>
    <div class="related"><strong>Related products</strong><br />
        <?php echo $related_content; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know!